# model.parameters() does not produce an iterable of Tensors

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to use torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_() which requires an iterable of Tensors.  See below

```html
for epoch in progress_bar(range(num_epochs)): 
    lstm.train()
    outputs = lstm(trainX.to(device))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(lstm.parameters(), 1)
```

My code errors with:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-4cd34e6fd44d> in <module>
     28     lstm.train()
     29     outputs = lstm(trainX.to(device))
---> 30     torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(lstm.parameters(), 1)
     31 
     32 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.py in clip_grad_norm_(parameters, max_norm, norm_type)
     28         total_norm = max(p.grad.detach().abs().max() for p in parameters)
     29     else:
---> 30         total_norm = torch.norm(torch.stack([torch.norm(p.grad.detach(), norm_type) for p in parameters]), norm_type)
     31     clip_coef = max_norm / (total_norm + 1e-6)
     32     if clip_coef < 1:

RuntimeError: stack expects a non-empty TensorList
```

If I example lstm.parameters() I get a list of Parameters, instead of a list of Tensors:

```html
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048, 1])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048, 512])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048, 512])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048, 512])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([2048])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([1, 512])
<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([1])
```

Looking at the first Parameter, it is a list of Tensors:

```html
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1])
.
.
.
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyTorch`'s `clip_grad_norm`, as the name suggests, operates on gradients.
You have to calculate your `loss` from `output`, use `loss.backward()` and perform gradient clipping afterwards.

Also, you should use `optimizer.step()` **after** this operation.

**Something like this:**

```
for epoch in progress_bar(range(num_epochs)): 
    lstm.train()
    for batch in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = lstm(trainX.to(device))
        loss = my_loss(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(lstm.parameters(), 1)
        optimizer.step()
```

You don't have `parameter.grad` calculated (it's value is `None`) and that's the reason of your error.